# IntelliJ says, should probably not be passed as parameter x

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Given this code:

```
private static class Building {
    private final int left;
    private final int right;
    private final int height;

    private Building(int left, int right, int height) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

private PriorityQueue<Building> createMaxHeapByHeight() {
    return new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Building>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Building o1, Building o2) {
            return -Integer.compare(o1.height, o2.height);
        }
    });
}
```

IntelliJ shows a warning for the comparison line above, saying:

> ```
> return -Integer.compare(o1.height, o2.height);
> //                      ^^^^^^^^^
> //                      'height' should probably not be passed as parameter 'x'
> ```

The warning can be suppressed with a comment on the statement:

> ```
> //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
> ```

Ok, but what is so suspicious here?

Also, if I change the compared field to `left` or to `right` (just for the sake of playing and investigating), the warning shifts to the second parameter, for example:

> ```
> return -Integer.compare(o1.right, o2.right);
> //                                ^^^^^^^^
> //                                'right' should probably not be passed as parameter 'y'
> ```

Again, what is so suspicious here? Why does it complain about the first parameter for the field `height`, and about the second parameter for the fields `left` and `right`? What's the logic here?

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly although you can try to wade through this - http://breandan.net/2014/04/20/intellij-inspections/  Basically, it is worried you're making a mistake/typo in your arg ordering/choice. Easily avoided by just returning o1.height - o2.height (faster too!)

Comment: @pvg - That approach will overflow for large values...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth sure but there's nothing stopping you from enforcing the range at construction. It's not like negative height makes sense either.

Comment: @pvg - You're right, in this particular use-case, it's probably fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you look up the inspection in settings, its description states following:

> Reports assignments and function calls where the name of the variable
>   to which a value is assigned or the function parameter does not seem
>   to match the name of the value assigned to it. For example:
>
> ```
> var x = 0;
> var y = x;
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> var x = 0, y = 0;
> var rc = new Rectangle(y, x, 20, 20);
> ```
>
> The configuration pane allows to specify the names which should not be
>   used together: the error is reported if the parameter name or
>   assignment target name contains words from one group and the name of
>   the assigned or passed variable contains words from a different group.

Because the signature of `Integer.compare` is `public static int compare(int x, int y)`, IntelliJ gets confused and thinks that you are trying to pass something that semantically represents height to a parameter `x` that should probably represent some horizontal offset, given its name.

You can remove the group of these names from the inspection settings to fix this (or disable the inspection entirely):

[image]

Comment: This feature may allow my cat to write code that works.

Answer (score 8):

You can see the logic here: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/210e0ed138627926e10094bb9c76026319cec178/java/java-analysis-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInspection/suspiciousNameCombination/SuspiciousNameCombinationInspectionBase.java

The relevant chunk is this:

```
public SuspiciousNameCombinationInspection() {
    addNameGroup("x,width,left,right");
    addNameGroup("y,height,top,bottom");
}
```

`x` is deemed compatible with `width`, `left` and `right`, but not with `height` (and vice versa).